# URL Extractor in Google Scripts getting TypeError

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, hyperlink, formula, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create a script that will extract hidden hyperlinks from the first column of a google sheet and place just the link in the column to the right.

This si the code I have so far:

```html
function getURL() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var range = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 1; i<=range; i++){
    var link = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getRichTextValue().getLinkURL();
    sheet.getRange(i, 2).setValue(link);
  }
 
}
```

but I keep getting an error that says:

```html
TypeError: sheet.getRange(...).getRichTextValue(...).getLinkURL is not a function
getURL  @ Code.gs:8
```

I've looked it up and I believe that getLinkURl should be a function, so I'm not sure what to do. Any help is appreciated -- thanks!

Comment: It's a typo in your code. You meant getLinkUrl() -- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value#getLinkUrl()

Comment: amazing thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this correction

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getLastRow();
  var values = sheet.getRange("A1:A"+range).getRichTextValues()
  for (var i = 1; i <= values.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i, 2).setValue(values[i-1][0].getLinkUrl());
  }
}
```